# What is the optimum layout for a hydrogen compressor, that would have least wear and tear on the compressor?

Tags: pressure, compressors, compressed-gases

I have been investing time in understanding the layout/schematic of a compressor that would be used for compressing hydrogen to high pressure ratings.
It's not clear to me what is the best design - whether it would be better to have multiple reciprocating piston compressors and intermediate storage tanks, or many intermediate storage tanks and 1 reciprocating piston compressor that is significantly used, or multiple reciprocating piston compressors.
To put this in two comparative diagrams:

#### Legend

```
C - Reciprocating compressor
T - intermediate hydrogen storage tank
```

#### Many pistons & intermediate storage tanks

`Input --> --C--T--C--T--C-- --> Output`

#### 1 piston with many intermediate storage tanks

```
          T-+-T
            |            
Input --> --C-- --> Output
            |
            T
```

(There are 3 different tanks that store the compressed hydrogen at different Bar, separated by valves)

#### Many pistons, no intermediate storage tanks

`Input --> --C--C--C-- --> Output`

For the sake of this example, let's say I'm attempting to increase the pressure up to 64 Bar (928.2~ PSI), and each reciprocating piston compressor can compress by the same ratio (1:4).

Could anyone shed light on which layout would be the best one to use to compress hydrogen, while minimising wear and tear on the compressor? (Equally if there is a completely different design highlight that!)

Comment: For nat gas it would likely be 3 different size/pressure cylinders ; one for each pressure. Probably all on the same machine.  Cooper Bessemer made equipment like this years ago, but I have been retired a long time. The valves are the usual wear/limiting component.